# Show that there are no entire functions such that $\bigcup_{n = 0}^{\infty} \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : f^{(n)}(z) = 0 \} = \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series, singularity

> Show that there are no entire functions such that $\bigcup_{n = 0}^{\infty} \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : f^{(n)}(z) = 0 \} = \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt: So I tried this by contradiction. Suppose there is an entire function $g(z)$ that satisfied this claim. WLOG, suppose that $g(z)$ is non constant. Then, I picked $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the least $j \in \mathbb{N}$ so that
$$ \big( \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \big)^{j} f(x) \neq 0. $$

Since $g$ is entire, I defined a taylor series expansion like this:

$$g(z) = \sum_{k = j}^{\infty}  \frac{\big( \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \big)^{k} f(x)(z -x)^k}{k!}$$

> I want to try to get that $g(z) = 0$ which would be my contradiction. I am not sure I am heading toward the right direction.
>
> Can you please give some feedback if I did it right or not? Please give me hints only.

Thank you so much, guys!!

Comment: since $f^{(n)}$ is entire for each $n$, it suffices to show any entire function has only countably many zeroes, but this is obvious, for otherwise, there would be some ball containing uncountably many, and then the roots in there would have a limit point, which they can't, for otherwise the function is identically zero (which I presume you meant to exclude in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contradiction: take $f(z)\equiv 0$ Then $f(z)$ is an entire function satisfying the given condition.

However, there would be no such non constant entire function. If there is, then by identity theorem, we get a contradiction.

Comment: This is very clunky. The zero function does not have this property.